# python socket issues reading ip

Tags: python

I have a PortScanner that allows the user to enter a IP and it scans for open ports. I'm having an issue that I don't quite understand. I have access to a bunch of servers so I tried the scanner on them. On half of the servers it works on the other half it just sits there endlessly running until I break out of it. I noticed the problem with IPs that had 2 digits in the string as opposed to 3 like: 199.110.13.300, however I just tried it on local 192.168.1.1 and it worked so I'm not sure whats causing the inconsistency.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
target = input("Enter IP to check: ")
maxPort = 1000

def scanner(port):
    try:
        sock.connect((target, port))
        return True
    except:
        return False

for portNumber in range(1,int(maxPort)):
    if scanner(portNumber):
        print('[*] Port', portNumber, '/tcp','is open')
```

Comment: Give an example of a problem ip please

Comment: Have you tried adding some logging, debugging with pdb, or running under strace? You need more information, and those are normal ways to get it. Also, how long is "endless"? If connect is waiting for a TCP timeout instead of getting an explicit reject, that takes _ages_.

Comment: If you would have read my post you would have seen it wasnt supposed to be. I was using it as an example. Ips with two digits in the address, like I showed after the second decimal, seem to cause problems. Im not going to post my server ips for you, hence the example. Read the whole post before you comment.

Answer (score 1):

My first guess is that the socket is hanging either due to waiting for receipt of information (less likely since you aren't using `socket.recv()`) or that the OS of the remote server didn't do a clean disconnect so TCP doesn't allow a connection from the same server. Here are a few helpful threads on the respective issues:

- [python sockets stop recv from hanging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20289981/python-sockets-stop-recv-from-hanging)
- [python socket hangs on connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7214553/python-socket-hangs-on-connect)