# Python class not able to handle exception

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

Server:

```
import tlib
import logging
import os
import time

logging.basicConfig(level=os.environ.get("LOGLEVEL", "DEBUG"))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    serverSocket = tlib.Server('localhost', 9090)
```

tlib:

```
import socket
import logging
import time

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class Server():
    def __init__(self, address, port, workers=5):
        self.address = address
        self.port = port
        self.workers = workers
        try:
            if self.mySocket:
                time.sleep(0.001)
        except:
            self.mySocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            self.mySocket.bind((address, port))
            self.mySocket.listen(5)
```

I feel like this should work, but I keep getting `AttributeError: 'Server' object has no attribute 'mySocket'`

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Unable to reproduce. What probably happens is that you get another exception in the `except` block, and the interpreter still shows you the `AttributeError` as well.

Comment: The other error I'm getting is in server.py: it tries to create serverSocket twice, and I don't know why -- I thought the __name__ == '__main__' was supposed to fix it

Comment: Then close the socket first. This is unrelated to the try-except blocks. Btw, it's customary to use an explicit Exception class instead of a catch-all to not inadvertently skip and exception for which you _do_ want the program to fail. Or not use exceptions here at all (though they are considered kind of pythonic in this context).

Comment: I can't get the socket to open long enough to use it because it errors before I can even create the object

Comment: Running the __init__ function runs my main file a second time for some reason

Comment: Maybe this can help?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7214553/python-socket-hangs-on-connect I think you should edit this or open a new question with the _actual_ problem, the try-except is not it.

Comment: where have you defined mySocket on the Server class?

Comment: unless you're defining `mySocket` in `__new__` (it seems like not because it is not shown), it is not possible for `self.mySocket` to exist before the first line in the `except` block, so `try` will always fail. Aside from that, I don't think we have all the information here, because as written, the code in the except block should run just fine (cannot reproduce).

Comment: does your code call `raise` anywhere without giving an exception to be raised? if so, it will just recall the last exception which may have been caught

Answer (score 0):

Changed the port, everything works now. No clue what was going on.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're hard-coding the socket but not configuring it, it's probable that you re-ran the script within TIME_WAIT delay: by default when a socket is closed it's not immediately reusable, instead it's put into the `TIME_WAIT` state, which can last [up to 4 minutes](http://www.serverframework.com/asynchronousevents/2011/01/time-wait-and-its-design-implications-for-protocols-and-scalable-servers.html). During this time, the specific socket (host, port pair) can not be reused.

That aside, the code makes very little sense:

- `__init__` is what Python calls to initialise an object, there is no reason for `mySocket` to be defined in any call, you're triggering exceptions for nothing.
- A bare `except` is a truly awful idea, it will catch core exceptions like `KeyboardException` and `SystemExit` which should never be caught unless they're going to be unconditionally re-raised.
- Passing a `backlog` parameter is not usually useful: unless the connections are *permanent*, if you limit the backlog and clients to the same value you preclude the possibility for a client to... just wait for a spot in the backlog, instead the clients will have to actively poll the server to try and grab a spot.
- Why even bother storing the address and port if you're going to create & store a socket object? The socket already stores that information (to the extent that there's any reason to recover it after having opened the socket).